# /translate API doesnt detect the language properly where as /detect does for the same text

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Below is the example , I understand the score is 0 for translate, but is it not supposed to detect the language at least especially when the detect API is working as expected for the same text ?

Detect API

```
POST https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/detect?api-version=3.0
[{"Text":"ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿಗೆ"}]
```

Response :

```
[{"language":"Knda","score":1.0,"isTranslationSupported":false,"isTransliterationSupported":true}]
```

Translate API

```
POST https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?to=en&api-version=3.0
[
    {"Text":"ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿಗೆ"}
]
```

Response :

```
[{"detectedLanguage":{"language":"en","score":0.0},"translations":[{"text":"ಬಾ ಇಲ್ಲಿಗೆ","to":"en"}]}]
```

If the detect API is able to return the language properly , translate should at least return the detected language properly , as of now it looks completely wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Translate detects among the translatable languages, English as default. Detect detects languages Translator doesn't translate.

Comment: how do we achieve this by just calling one API ? it looks like the response from translate API kind of misleading or can be improved .